# pandas dataframe filter a column with a key word based on the aggregation of another column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

Imagine I have the following dataframe df:

```
Contract_Id, date, product, qty
1,2016-08-06,a,1
1,2016-08-06,b,2
1,2017-08-06,c,2
2,2016-08-06,a,1
3,2016-08-06,a,2
3,2017-08-06,a,2
4,2016-08-06,b,2
4,2017-09-06,a,2
```

I am trying to find out whether each contract id has product b or product a and return 2 columns.

Ideal output:

```
Contract_Id, date, product, qty, contract_id_has_a, contract_id_has_b
1,2016-08-06,a,1,True,True
1,2016-08-06,b,2,True,True
2,2016-08-06,a,1,True,False
3,2016-08-06,a,2,True,False
4,2016-08-06,b,2,False,True
```

This will only return whether this row has product a or not

```
df[‘product’].str.contains('a', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
```

I tried:

```
import re 

df[‘product’].groupby([‘Contract_Id']).str.contains('a', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)

KeyError: ‘Contract_Id'
```

Could anyone enlighten? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform grouping but return values for all original rows at the end (and not just for every group) you should use the [pd.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function. Then you could check if any of the group matches, and set it for all rows.

This would work:

```
df['contract_id_has_a'] = df.groupby('Contract_Id')['product'].transform(lambda x: x.str.contains('a').any())
```

Comment: Thank you! should be ```df.groupby('Contract_Id')['product'].transform(lambda x: x.str.contains('a').any())```